# How to change div img when scrolling down a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Pretty simple javascript issue that I am not sure how to do:

When scrolling down on the website:
http://cerebral-supplements.myshopify.com/ (use password "aiglog")

the header shifts up into a minimalistic design. As the logo is too big it sticks out.

What javascript code would be needed to change the logo's div properties to resize the image?

Thanks

Comment: There is a password to enter the store.

Comment: sorry please use password

aiglog

Answer (score 0):

modify the functions values to your needs.

```
function onScrollChange()
{
    if ( document.body.scrollTop > 500 ) {
        var divElement = document.getElementById('divID');

        // either change style properties directly
        divElement.style.width = '100px';
        divElement.style.height = '100px';
        // or change the div's css class
        divElement.classname = 'smallLogoClass';

    }
}
```

than register it, so it executes on each scroll.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add custom CSS, add the following:

```
/* scale logo down to ~75% size when scrolled sidebar is activated (fadeInDown class) */
.fadeInDown .template-logo img {
   width: 225px;
   height: 61px;
}
```

Comment: this is not a javascript solution

Comment: @dreamlab you are right. I half misread the question but mostly believe that if it can be fixed with CSS, that is a better option.

Comment: you could a least provide how to apply the css on scroll down

Comment: @dreamlab please feel free to edit the answer if you can improve it but I'm honestly not sure what you're talking about

Comment: ohh. i see. he already adds the .fadeInDown class on the site. this is not stated in the question.

Comment: Yes- this answer builds upon existing application of the CSS class whether the author knows it or it's automatically applied by his theme or shopify itself

Comment: Actually maybe he will like this solution more as he may not know CSS can do the work. I personally think that this is neater.